# Is there a benefit to having a constant buffer be dynamic vs immediate indexed?

Tags: optimization, shader, hlsl, direct3d

I'm writing a fragment shader and was happily able to do it without branches. I need to make a modified version that will require a branch, so I rewrote the original to see what the compiler did with the branch, if it was optimized out or caused a big difference.

The disassembled code ([see here](https://www.diffchecker.com/qIXoo5YT)) showed 3 fewer math operations, one additional temp register, and four additional instructions. That all makes sense to me, but the one thing that jumped out was this line:

The original: `dcl_constantbuffer CB0[9], dynamicIndexed`
The branching version: `dcl_constantbuffer CB0[9], immediateIndexed`

I assume this is because the new code was able to be unrolled or whatever the compiler does to make the access pattern more predictable. My question is, does this imply some performance benefit, or should I just stick with the "fewer instructions are better" rule of thumb?

(note: I tried profiling but I wasn't able to get consistent results. I'm mostly just trying to understand the underlying concept.)